# How to capture full node screenshot in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot

Chrome developer tools allows to capture node screenshots.
Unfortunately, it only captures visible part of node. I need full node.

There's also "Capture full size screenshot" command, but it captures full page. I only need single node.

So, how can I capture full node(it's higher than screen)?

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the styles of the node so it's visible in full length and then take node screenshot or remove other elements of the page and take the full page screenshot.

With node screenshot:

- edit styles of the node so it stretches to full height (remove height, max-height etc.)
- remove neighbouring elements if necessary
- capture node screenshot.

With page screenshot:

- move the node you want to screenshot so it's a direct descendant of the `body` tag
- remove other visible elements of the page
- edit styles of the node so it stretches to full height
- take a full page screenshot.

Elements of the page can be removed using "Delete element" option.